# How to make "Google sheets" alike table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, html-table

I have to make a copy of the google docs. And right now I am working on tables. How to make "Google sheets" alike or "Handsontable" alike table(editable on click, ability to highlight and etc), not just "table, tr, td". I'm not allowed to use APIs, so I would like to know how to make that grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google docs uses a canvas element and then paints the grid on the canvas. I assume they have some custom implementation of a grid system to have it work without being slow.

If you don't care about performance:

```
const grid = new Array(100); // Or whatever width;
grid.fill(new Array(100));

grid.forEach(column => {
    column.fill('');
    column.forEach(cell=> {
         const cellInput = document.createElement('input');
         $('div#output').append(cellInput);
    });
});
```

The above code will fill a div that has an id of 'output' with 10,000 input elements. Then you can click and edit each one. You could lay them out with css grid:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

How you gather the inputs and manipulate them is up to you.

Comment: Hi can you check out my code at JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufk86bag/1/ . It is not working

Comment: My fault, forEach skips over empty items. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to using react.js. Here is a link to
[React Table examples](https://reactjsexample.com/tag/table/)

Comment: He says he's using jquery, not React.